# steamauth error headers already sent

Tags: php

I have a error in my script and I can't find out why the error is coming.

Here is the file that i have an error in:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require ('openid.php');

function logoutbutton() {
    echo "<form action=\"steamauth/logout.php\" method=\"post\"><input value=\"Logout\" type=\"submit\" /></form>"; //logout button
}

function steamlogin()
{
try {
    require("settings.php");
    $openid = new LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);

    $button['small'] = "small";
    $button['large_no'] = "large_noborder";
    $button['large'] = "large_border";
    $button = $button[$steamauth['buttonstyle']];

    if(!$openid->mode) {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
            $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }

    return "<form action=\"?login\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"image\" src=\"http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_".$button.".png\"></form>";
    }

     elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {
        if($openid->validate()) { 
                $id = $openid->identity;
                $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

                $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1]; 
                include_once("link.php");
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."'");
                if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
                {
                    $time=time();
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (steamid,reg) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['steamid']."','$time')") or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
                }
                //Determine the return to page. We substract "login&"" to remove the login var from the URL.
                //"file.php?login&foo=bar" would become "file.php?foo=bar"
                $returnTo = str_replace('login&', '', $_GET['openid_return_to']);
                //If it didn't change anything, it means that there's no additionals vars, so remove the login var so that we don't get redirected to Steam over and over.
                if($returnTo === $_GET['openid_return_to']) $returnTo = str_replace('?login', '', $_GET['openid_return_to']);
                header('Location: '.$returnTo);
        } else {
                echo "User is not logged in.\n";
        }

    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}

?>
```

The error is on line 24

This part:

```
if(!$openid->mode) {
    if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
        $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
        header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
    }
```

This is a Steam login script that makes users able to login to my website, I would like if someone could help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to defer calling `session_start()` until after the code block you have identified. Calling `session_start()` send HTTP headers to the browser. Once that happens you can no longer use the LOCATION header to redirect to the login page.